# postgres - jsonb field with arbitrary json - indexing ok?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgres table that I need to store arbitrary key/value pairs in, and some of the values could be arrays. I see that postgres supports JSONB and Array field types, and was considering using JSONB, and have been [reviewing the JSONB docs on indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)

The thing I'm trying to understand is if the field can be indexed effectively, given that there will be increasingly different json schemas stored in the field?

For example, say I have a table to store plugin data, and those plugins will each be allowed to store as many keys as they want, per user.

**Can I effectively store data in this field, and have it's indexes perform well, given that**

- the number of plugins will increase, but will probably be < 100
- the json field values will mostly be simple json objects, one level deep
- I am in full control of what the json schema will look like, for each plugin, if that helps.

#### plugin_data

| key | value(JSONB) | plugin_type | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| plugin.one | {id:1, test:'two'} | one | 100 |
| plugin.one | {id:32, test:'my title'} | one | 102 |
| plugin.two | {schedule:52, count:5, increment:2} | two | 200 |
| plugin.three | {duration:10s} | three | 200 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [you can index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) the column with a GIN index. That will speed up searches for keys with `?`, `?&` and `?|` as well as the containment operator `@>` to search if a "subobject" is contained.